# jQuery Drop Revert to Original Position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

i write a code for drag n drop delete. user can drag item to trash then comes confirm message, if confirm delete it, and want to if user not confirm deletion the item need go its original position, help me please

```
//drag code
 var a = 3;
        $('#dragZone .box,#dragZone .box1,#dragZone .box2').draggable({containment:".invitemain"}, {
            start:function (event, ui) {
                $(this).css("z-index", a++);
            },
            stop:function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("mid");
                var x = $(this).position().left;
                var y = $(this).position().top;
                var z = $(this).css("z-index");

//send request to server to save the position
                $.get('/users/savecodes?mid=' + id + '&x=' + x + '&y=' + y + '&z=' + z, function (data) {
                    //alert(data);    
                }); 

            }    
        });

//drop code
 $("#trash").droppable({
            tolerance: 'touch',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                var answer = confirm('Permanently delete this item?');                 
                if(answer){
                    //call some ajax for delete
                $(ui.draggable).remove();
                }
                else{
                    //move to original position
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Look into using the ```revert``` option.  You can either pass it in when creating the ```draggable``` or set it on the fly using ```$('my-selector').draggable('option', revert, true);```.

Answer (score -1):

```
function stopDrag{
$("#trash").draggable({ cancel: "button" }); 
}
```

and the call your function

```
$(ui.draggable).remove();
            }
            else{
               stopDrag();
            }
```

i think this may work i didn't try it myself but i checked this link : http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-cancel so give it a try

and check this link also it's just what are you looking for : http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/